# ADFS single sign-on with external authentication provider

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, adfs2.0, adfs, saml-2.0

We're establishing an ADFS (2.0) that will be responsible for authenticating users for several, customer-facing systems. The authentication mechanism is out-sourced to an external partner, which offers access to several authentication providers.

We recently ran into the following scenario :

1. A user attempts to access customer-facing system A and is redirected to the ADFS for authentication.
2. The ADFS redirects the user to the authentication partner, where he authenticates succesfully.
3. The user is sent back to the ADFS with his authentication token.
4. The ADFS sends the user back to system A. He now has a session with it.
5. The user attempts to access System B, in which he is not yet
   authenticated, and is sent to the ADFS.

This is where the ADFS strays from the behaviour we expected. Instead of recognizing the user, and transparently sending him back to System B with a valid authentication token, the ADFS sends him to our authentication partner for re-authentication.

This completely destroys the SSO functionality we wanted for customers using systems A and B, but we have not found a way to have the ADFS establish a user session and re-using that during access to the second system.

Has anyone solved this problem?

Can ADFS only deliver single sign-on when it's wholly responsible for authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The ADFS is expected to behave this way, if your RP-s (System A and System B) have been configured to Force Authentication (ForceAuthn="true"). To resolve your issue, ensure that the freshness attribute is removed from the `<wsFederation>` element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it unfortunately didn't solve the problem. I think the difference is that in our scenario, the AD FS is not actually doing the authentication, but relaying the authentication from another IDP.

Comment: This is a typical scenario, where the ADFS acts as Federation Provider (FP). Anyways, going back to my answer, I would suggest you to inspect the SAML Authentication Request with e.g. SAML tracer, and ensure that the attribute ForceAuthn is not present in it.

Answer (score 0):

In classic ADFS, you set up the different authentication partners as claims providers with ADFS i.e. you federate the respective STS. This then provides the SSO functionality that you require.

It sounds like your problem is that there is only federation between ADFS and the external partner but not between ADFS and the authentication providers handled by the external partner.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the ADFS2 logs? In a **Windows machine --> Event Viewer --> Applications and Services Logs --> AD FS 2.0 --> Admin**.

Check also that A,B and ADFS2 are in the same *circle of trust*, and also the *Assertion Consumer Services* endpoints of the system B.

Hope it helps,

Luis